# Tensorflow: getting outputs form bidirectional_rnn with variable sequence length

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm using `tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn` with the `sequence_length` parameter for variable input size, and I can't figure out how to get the final output for each sample in the minibatch:

```
output, _, _ = tf.nn.bidirectional_rnn(forward1,backward1,input,dtype=tf.float32,sequence_length=input_lengths)
```

Now, if I had constant sequence lengths, I would simply use `output[-1]` and get the final output. In my case I have variable sequences (their lengths are known). 
Also, is this output the output of both forward and backward LSTMs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered by looking at the source code [rnn.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py).

For sequences with dynamic length, the source code says:

> If the sequence_length vector is provided, dynamic calculation is
>   performed.   This method of calculation does not compute the RNN steps
>   past the maximum   sequence length of the minibatch (thus saving
>   computational time),   and properly propagates the state at an
>   example's sequence length   to the final state output.

Therefore, in order to get the actual last output, you should slice the resulting output.

For bidirectional_rnn, the source code says:

> A tuple (outputs, output_state_fw, output_state_bw) where:
>         outputs is a length `T` list of outputs (one for each input), which
>           are depth-concatenated forward and backward outputs.
>         output_state_fw is the final state of the forward rnn.
>         output_state_bw is the final state of the backward rnn.

Therefore, the output is a tuple rather than a tensor.
You can concatenate this tuple into a vector if you wish.